# Extracting character font size from PDF files with R

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining

I've been trying to reproduce a similar dataset (not exactly the same, I stress) explained in this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7955/9bc8cff7f81699a63e8c43548753041cd920.pdf) for a similar purpose. But I'm having trouble in coming up with an idea for getting font size while coding in R. Other solutions seem to be available in other coding languages.

For instance, one could very easily extract information regarding number of characters in a page or transforming each page in a image and obtaining data regarding number of pixels and such - which will be part of my metadata anyway. Such as in the example below:

```
library(pdftools)
library(png)

download.file("http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2805.pdf", "1403.2805.pdf", mode = "wb")

txt <- pdf_text("1403.2805.pdf")

num_char_page = unlist(lapply(txt,nchar))

height = 1:length(txt)
width =1:length(txt)

for (i in 1:length(txt)) {

  bitmap <- pdf_render_page("1403.2805.pdf", page = i)

  png::writePNG(bitmap, paste0("page",i,".png"))

  photo=readPNG(paste0("page",i,".png"))

  height[i]  = dim(photo)[1]

  width[i] = dim(photo)[2]

}

layout_df = data.frame(page=1:length(txt), num_char_page=num_char_page, height=height, width=width)
```

So this is fairly straightforward, although the code could be made faster with some lapply version of it in the loop part (maybe). But I have no idea on how to obtain font size. How would I do it? Specially if we assume a scanned version of the documents, such as in the aforementioned paper.

---

**Observation**: I will ask it in a separate question probably, but I would cherish if someone could pinpoint to some ideas regarding margin sizes and spacing between lines in the comments.

**Second Observation**: I think (in this particular case) the PDF that I've used as an example could have meta-data which could enable font-size extraction. But I am trying to obtain font size from scanned (and maybe OCR'd) PDFs. One could transform the pages of the PDF (in the example) into images and then transform them again into non-OCR'd PDFs, which might be somewhat similar to the scanned PDF situation.

Comment: On the png::writePNG statement, do you need another closing parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, already edit it.

Comment: I am trying to do similar analyses of survey reports in PDF format that are published by law firms.  Can we chat or email about our respective research and tools?

Comment: Yes, of course o/

Comment: Great, how do I reach you or you reach me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not possible to determine the actual font size, at least not without knowing the exact font and its specifications. [see here for an explanation of why](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly)

If you just want to compare font size between documents, it might be sufficient to use average line height as the comparison, which might be easier to do. If you don't care about the actual values and only need to know relative size between documents, the following might work. You would have to consider, or avoid, the potential effect of different document sizes and/or DPI.

```
library(tesseract)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- ocr_data("http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2805.pdf")

df %>% 
  separate(bbox, c('x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'), convert = T) %>% 
  mutate(line_height = y2 - y1) %>% 
  summarise(avg_line_height = mean(line_height))

# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   avg_line_height
#             <dbl>
# 1            58.7
```

example for average letter height and width....

```
df %>%
  separate(bbox, c('x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'), convert = T) %>%
  mutate(word_height = y2 - y1) %>%
  mutate(word_width = x2 - x1) %>%
  mutate(num_letters = nchar(word)) %>%
  mutate(avg_letter_width = word_width / num_letters) %>%
  summarise(avg_letter_height = mean(word_height),
            avg_letter_width = mean(avg_letter_width))

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   avg_letter_height avg_letter_width
#               <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1              58.7             37.3
```

and if you want to do it per page, you can use `pdftools` to render each page of a multi-page PDF individually and the run `ocr_data` on each one, then combine...

```
library(pdftools)
library(tesseract)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

download.file(url = "http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2805.pdf",
              destfile = pdf_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"))

page_pngs <-
  lapply(seq_len(pdf_info(pdf_path)$pages), function(page_num) {
    pdf_convert(pdf_path, pages = page_num, dpi = 300)
  })

df <-
  bind_rows(
    lapply(seq_len(length(page_pngs)), function(page_num) {
      ocr_data(page_pngs[[page_num]]) %>%
        separate(bbox, c('x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'), convert = T) %>%
        mutate(word_height = y2 - y1) %>%
        mutate(word_width = x2 - x1) %>%
        mutate(num_letters = nchar(word)) %>%
        mutate(avg_letter_width = word_width / num_letters) %>%
        mutate(page = page_num) %>%
        select(page, letter_height = word_height, letter_width = avg_letter_width)
    })
  )

df %>%
  group_by(page) %>%
  summarise(avg_letter_height = mean(letter_height),
            avg_letter_width = mean(letter_width)) %>%
  mutate(avg_letter_area = avg_letter_height * avg_letter_width)

# # A tibble: 29 x 4
#     page avg_letter_height avg_letter_width avg_letter_area
#    <int>             <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#  1     1              29.4             17.9            525.
#  2     2              29.3             18.9            554.
#  3     3              30.0             19.1            574.
#  4     4              30.2             18.7            565.
#  5     5              29.8             19.0            566.
#  6     6              28.2             17.7            498.
#  7     7              28.9             18.3            529.
#  8     8              29.8             18.6            554.
#  9     9              29.1             18.6            541.
# 10    10              28.3             18.3            519.
# # ... with 19 more rows
```

Comment: Is there an alternative for constructing width? If I construct an average value with area (width x height) and number of characters per line(something like the average of number of character divided by the area), I might get something sufficiently close to character font-size.

Comment: tesseract returns the bounding box for each word, so you could calculate word_with/num_of_chars = avg_letter_width per word.

Comment: see new example above

Comment: I think the `ocr_data` function does not work that well. Pages 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 (and others) do not produce a tibble. Do you think we could have an alternative regarding this aspect? Maybe transforming the png files into a higher resolution. I'll try that.

Comment: tesseract is one of the oldest, best OCR systems that I'm aware of. Using exactly my example code above, all pages are successfully OCR'd and the data frames are created and merged. Maybe some other error is happening on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I think that could be the problem. I'll try in a different machine just to be sure.